# How could I return a view with controller@index in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to send data of `Category::all()` to a view. But I can't to use the @index() of controller. I think to use something like this, but it's a wrong way 'cause this will not to be used in other views.

```
$categories = Category::all();
return view('view')->with('categories', $categories)
```

What is the right way to return all to a .blade view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's a wrong way 'cause this will not to be used in other views.

I understood this question as you want to call all categories in all view files.

You can either create your own [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) (`ViewServiceProvider` name is common) or you can use the existing `AppServiceProvider`.

In your selected provider, put your code in the boot method.

```
public function boot() {
    $categories = Category::all();
    view()->share('categories ', $categories);
}
```

This will make a `$categories` variable accessible in all your views.

*If you rather want to use the facade instead of the helper, change `view()->` to `View::` but don't forget to have `use View;` at the top of your file.*

Answer (score 0):

In your view method write the directory and name of the blade without '.blade'

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve data as follow:

```
public function getData() {
  $categories = Category::all();
  return view('yourview', compact('categories'));
}
```

Then Inside yourview you can retrieve data as folow:

```
@foreach($categories as $cat)
 <p> {{ $cat->name }} </p>
@endforeach
```